# How to use speech recognition with/on video file?

Tags: c++, video, speech-recognition

How can I code speech recognition engine (Using Microsoft Speech SDK) to "listen" a video file and save the detection into a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499608/transcribing-wma-mp3-audio-in-an-automated-fashion/1665318#1665318) and has a very similar answer.  You need to separate out the audio portion, convert it to WAV format, and send it to an inproc recognizer.

However, it has the same problems that I described before (requires training, assumes a single voice, and assumes the microphone is close to the speaker).   If that's the case, then you can likely get reasonably good results.  If that's not the case (i.e., you're trying to transcribe a TV show, or worse, some sort of camcorder audio), then the results will likely be unsatisfactory.